# PMA Close Reason Missing

Tags: support

When reviewing [Hair Transplant Donor Area extreme burn sensation and very itchy. Please help!](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/18216/hair-transplant-donor-area-extreme-burn-sensation-and-very-itchy-please-help) in the review **low quality posts** queue, I went to vote to close, but the Personal Medcial Advice close reason is missing

[image: close votes available]

as pointed out in the comments.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, for bringing it on Meta.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's missing because I edited it to replace the link to a meta post with a better one. That edit is awaiting approval from another mod. I did not know it would disappear during the wait.

EDIT: The close reason has been restored with a new link to [this answer](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/747/how-long-can-this-site-be-popular-if-everybody-is-asked-to-see-a-doctor/748#748).

Comment: Awesome! Dunno why I‘m only seeing this now. Can you add a status-completed to this request a year back? https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/763/linking-personal-close-reason-to-doctorwhoms-answer